# Chrome showing undefined for keyCode

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

So I have a dropdown list that when the user selects something from the list and presses enter instead of clicking, it is suppose to refresh the page with the selected data.

It is working perfect in IE and Firefox, but Safari & Chrome seem to be completely ignoring it.

Here is where I add the attribute to the dropdown list:

```
cboContext.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", "if (typeAhead(event,'" + cboContext.ClientID + "') == 1) contextPostback();");
```

It seems to be ignoring the OnKeyDown attribute in Chrome and Safari

**Edit:**

Based on the work and comments from Sime and Nil,  I have found out that Chrome is not recognizing the keyCode, it shows as undefined.

I have put my typeAhead() code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcMGP/1/)

Here is where I declare the variable for keyCode:

```
var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
```

Does anyone have any idea why it would be staying as undefined?

Comment: Please provide the generated HTML source code. (I'm assuming your code adds a HTML "onkeydown" attribute to the `<select>` element.)

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `typeAhead` function to check if it even executes in Chrome/Safari. And while you're in it, you can step through its code to see what it returns (and why it doesn't return `1`).

Comment: When I first hit enter, it does nothing.. but then when I hit enter again, it goes into the function but selects the first item in the list and not the one you select

Comment: I can confirm that behavior in Chrome. **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nQhUT/ The first ENTER does not trigger the "onkeydown" code, but the second ENTER does. However, in my demo, Chrome kept the selected option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "onchange" attribute (either in addition, or as a replacement for the "onkeydown" attribute).

In Chrome, when the SELECT element is open and ENTER is pressed, the "onchange" code executes.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nQhUT/3/

Comment: hmmm..  After looking at your live demo, I had high hopes... but it still appears to have the same effect.  When I change it to onchange, only thing that changes is that IE stops working as well

Comment: @Steve You mean, the "onchange" code doesn't even execute? Try `cboContext.Attributes.Add("onchange", "alert(0)")` to check...

Comment: onchange seems to fire when I put the code in that you just posted.. so it seems like it must be the typeAhead() function that chrome isn't liking now?

Comment: @Steve You'll have to check which value it returns in Chrome. You can set a break-point in the Chrome dev tools.

Comment: I looked through using the chrome dev tools and it doesn't seem to show any glaring issues...  such a weird problem

Comment: @Steve The code provided by Sime Vidas is working fine for me in Chrome. You might want to check out typeAhead function and what it returns. Please check for any error in console.

Comment: @Nil yeah I have checked my console for errors, I have one but it is from a css file not being found...  nothing pertaining to javascript or my typeahead function

Comment: @Steve It seems your typeAhead function is not returning 1. Would you try without typeAhead function using code provided by Sime Vidas?

Comment: @Nil okay so I changed my piece of code to - `cboContext.Attributes.Add("onchange", "if (typeAhead(event,'" + cboContext.ClientID + "') == 1){ contextPostback(); } else { alert('not returning 1'); }");` and it is indeed not returning 1.. now I am really confused.  Why would it return 1 in IE and Firefox but not Chrome

Comment: @Nil I noticed that this section of code in my typeAhead() never gets assigned in Chrome.. any ideas why?    `var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;`

Comment: Ok so I figured out my problem.  I used your code Sime but my issue was with `var selection = document.getElementById(nextFocus);` In Chrome it kept coming up as `undefined` so I added code to detect browsers and made var selection into `document.getElementById("nameofelement").selectedIndex;` which is the name of the element.  Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The event names are case sensitive. The event should be "onkeydown". IE may not enforce this?

```
cboContext.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if (typeAhead(event,'" + cboContext.ClientID + "') == 1) contextPostback();");
```

Comment: The `onkeydown` property of DOM elements is case-sensitive, but the "onkeydown" HTML attribute isn't (which is what OP is setting). Also, OP posted the generated HTML source code and the "onkeydown" attribute is all lower-case (which means that the `Attributes.Add()` method converts the string name to lower-case).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

<strike>I am not sure what inputBuffer.accumString does in your typeAhead function,it was breaking code when I tried it with fiddle.</strike>

If you're trying to call typeAhead function with **onchange**, then charCode in your below code will be undefined. you can get keyCode only on Keyup/keyDown across browsers. Please check [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Event.keyCode-Demystified.aspx).

```
var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
```

If you check your function carefully, it just returns 1 and perform some operation on inputBuffer if key pressed is enter or tab else it returns -1.  If you can make your function work on **onchange** as suggested by **Šime Vidas** instead onkeydown/onkeyup, it will work across browsers.

Comment: I tried using OnKeyDown but Chrome seems to be ignoring that for some reason.  I updated the jsfiddle link to include what inputBuffer does

Comment: I don't know... I must be missing something.  I try to add the attribute onchange - then it stops working in all browsers...  just so confused.  In theory I agree, this should all work... but it's not.

Comment: Ok so I figured out my problem.  I ended up using Sime's code but my issue was with `var selection = document.getElementById(nextFocus);` In Chrome it kept coming up as `undefined` so I added code to detect browsers and made var selection into `document.getElementById("nameofelement").selectedIndex;` .  Thanks for all the help everyone!